# What to fill into main class in Intellij to pack all the examples into one jar?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar, apache-storm, mainclass

I'm trying to build a jar with Intellij, it requires a main class. The example I am using is [storm-starter](https://github.com/apache/storm/tree/master/examples/storm-starter). I want to pack all the examples to this jar.

What should I fill to main class so that I can pack all the examples into one jar?

Comment: use maven: $ mvn clean install -DskipTests=true

Comment: You will find the corresponding jar named "original-storm-starter-0.11.0-SNAPSHOT.jar" in folder "examples/storm-starter/target"
(The version number might differ of course, depending on the Storm version you are using.)